# Specific order, need order from XSL not from input xml format

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I am facing a problem with same name nodes at the same level and specific order. My order depends on the value of their nodes. My output should be a txt file. My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<header>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>10</value>
      <value>test</value>
    </element>
  </B>

  <A>
    <element>
      <value>100</value>
      <value>message</value>
    </element>
  </A>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>20</value>
      <value>phase</value>
    </element>
  </B>

  <A>
    <element>
      <value>101</value>
      <value>type</value>
    </element>
  </A>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>20</value>
      <value>phase</value>
    </element>
  </B>

  <A>
    <element>
      <value>101</value>
      <value>type</value>
    </element>
  </A>
</header>
```

My txt output should look like that.

**typephase
typephase**

and so on.

My XSL looks like that

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="header/*">

        <xsl:if test="name(.) = 'A' and element/value='101'">
            <xsl:value-of select="element/value[position()=2]" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="name(.) = 'B' and element/value='20'">
            <xsl:value-of select="element/value[position()=2]" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="header/*"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The result with this XSL is:

**phasetype
phasetype**

xsl:sort descending doesn`t help me, because the original input XML has much more nodes. I need the order from the XSL not from the input XML document. Does anyone know, how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a second XSL to run on the output?

Comment: no I dont`t, do you have a small example, how to do that?

Comment: just the same way that you did it the first time.  except you would use the output XML from the first XSL and then in the Second XSL you do the sort the way you want it.

Comment: You say that you need the order from the XSL file. But if you simply want to process `A` nodes with value `101` before `B` nodes with value `20`, the output would be `type type phase phase`. So according to which rule do you want to order the output exactly?

Comment: I think thats my problem, because I need the order **type phase type phase** and so on. **A B A B** and not **A A B B** . I dont know how to define a rule for that.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the ordering rule. Your input XML is like **B1 A1 B2 A2 B3 A3** (numbers added for clarity). Do you want **A3 B3 A2 B2**? Or do you want **A2 B2 A3 B3**?

Comment: In this case **A2 B2 A3 B3** I need that specific order and I think the main problem are my if querries. If I had not several xml tags with the same name, then I would have no problems. But I need the one value to identify which XML-Tag the right one is.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that the input XML always has elements in the order **B A B A ...** and that you don't have missing elements. I've also assumed that you only want **A** and **B** elements to appear in pairs, if they both have the correct value.

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Match the root element and apply-templates to all its child elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Find A elements with a value of 101, where the B element just before has a value of 20. -->
  <xsl:template match="A[element/value='101'][preceding-sibling::B[1][element/value='20']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="element/value[2]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::B[1]/element/value[2]"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Don't do anything with other A elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="A"/>

  <!-- Don't do anything else with B elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="B"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<header>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>10</value>
      <value>test1</value>
    </element>
  </B>
  <A>
    <element>
      <value>100</value>
      <value>message1</value>
    </element>
  </A>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>20</value>
      <value>phase2</value>
    </element>
  </B>
  <A>
    <element>
      <value>101</value>
      <value>type2</value>
    </element>
  </A>
  <B>
    <element>
      <value>20</value>
      <value>phase3</value>
    </element>
  </B>
  <A>
    <element>
      <value>101</value>
      <value>type3</value>
    </element>
  </A>
</header>
```

produces this output:

```
type2phase2 type3phase3
```

I've added numbers to the `value` elements from your example, to make it clearer what's being output.